# Getting an unexpected error in my MFC application

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, c-strings

I am trying to access the elements of `CString` character by character.
I'm getting an error in the following lines of code:

```
void CTOTALTIMECALCDlg::OnBnClickedOk()
{ 
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    CString lstring;
    m_Timeget.GetWindowText(lstring);
    MessageBox(lstring[0]);
    CDialogEx::OnOK();
}
```

**Error:**

> "Error    1   error C2664: 'int CWnd::MessageBoxW(LPCTSTR,LPCTSTR,UINT)' :
>   cannot convert argument 1 from 'wchar_t' to 'LPCTSTR'" at line
>   **"MessageBox(lstring[0]);"**

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to print the first character in your `MessageBox`, then don't expect from it to convert from `LPCTSTR` -> `LPCWSTR` (Unicode) -> *`const WCHAR*` to `wchar_t`*.

Print the whole `CString`, or properly print the first character.

```
void CTOTALTIMECALCDlg::OnBnClickedOk()
{ 
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    CString lstring;
    m_Timeget.GetWindowText(lstring);
    if (!lstring.IsEmpty())
        MessageBox(lstring.Left(1));
    CDialogEx::OnOK();
}
```

[MessageBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) accepts `LPCTSTR` as parameter.
`LPCTSTR` is resolved `const wchar_t*` in Unicode settings.
[`CString::operator[ ]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa300563%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) returns a `TCHAR` which is `wchar_t` in Unicode.
[`CString::operator LPCTSTR()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa300569%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) see below in code

```
//You are doing this:
MessageBox(wchar_t);
//It wants this:
MessageBox(wchar_t*);
//CString::Left will return a new CString
MessageBox(CString::Left . CString::operator LPCTSTR());
```

Comment: Am only using index as 0 to test whether am able to access the data,,, I want to do operations on the data present in that lstring and later display it in cstatic later in my gui

Comment: @user78766 You mentioned nothing of that in your question. You can access the data if the `CString` is not [`.IsEmpty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa300475%28v=vs.60%29.aspx). Also see [`CString::operator[ ]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa300563%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

Comment: Ya that's the point,, an unexpected error,,,, I already tried using [] and GetAt both functions returning same error,,,,I even tried initializing the string by seeing an example from msdn,,, even then am getting same error, as I see it the code seems to be fine,,something else is wrong!

Comment: @user78766 There's no unexpected error. The error in your question is expected. If the `MessageBox` expects an array or a pointer, then a single character will not do it. Please take a closer look into the parameters the `MessageBox` accepts. `wchar_t*` is not equal to `wchar_t`.